# tomcat PrintWriter has no output

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

i just installed Tomcat via Netbeans and created a new project. I just want to print some text on screen but only "Hello World!" is shown. Do i have to something specific to show text on screen?

**EDIT: [SOLVED] I do not know what the problem was. I just changed my IDE from Netbeans to Eclipse, now everything works**.

System: Ubunut 16.04 LTS 64Bit

```
    @WebServlet(name = "MicStreamReciever", urlPatterns = {"/MicStreamReciever"})
public class MicStreamReciever extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("processRequest");
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("doGet");

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);

    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: Why is 'Hello World' shown? Are you under the right URL?

Comment: in my project folder there is another folder named "Webpages" and there is an html file where "Hello World!" is written in.

Comment: Have you tried to open the URL ending on "/MicStreamReciever"? Like in http://host:port/context/MicStreamReciever.

Comment: @TobiasOtto yes, thats the only why i know to open the url